# Generate all lines in table when one cell contains several values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was not even sure how to give a title to my question.

I try to generate all the lines of a table when cells contain several values, example bellow will be more helpfull

Start table :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Alex, Tom | 1 |
| Alex, Mike | 2 |
| Tom, Mike | 3 |
| Alex | 3 |

Result I am aiming for

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 |
| Tom | 1 |
| Alex | 2 |
| Mike | 2 |
| Tom | 3 |
| Mike | 3 |
| Alex | 3 |

I manage to do it in two steps as per this [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTXBtedaIvNC18oHvA0nbRRYVsUOc_LpLkfsk20oWQA/edit#gid=562250172)

- Step 1 : =arrayformula(split(flatten(trim(split(A1:A4;","))&"|"&B1:B4);"|"))

I have unwanted empty results, I tried to solve them with QUERIES and SORT but I end up with errors when using FLATTEN with column B

- Step 2 : I filter the results to remove unwanted results

There may be another way but I lack skills here, many thanks in adavance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(trim(split(A1:A4,","))&"|"&B1:B4),"|",,0),"where Col1 is not null",0))
```

I've disabled the default *remove empty text* argument of the outer SPLIT to make sure that the numbers stay in the right column, then simply wrapped your formula in a QUERY to remove rows where no name is present (corresponding to the empty cells generated by the inner SPLIT as there are different numbers of names in each row).

Comment: Many thanks! I missed the extra parameter in the Split function!